# Load PipelineModel in Spark

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, load

I want to load a `PipelineModel` in Apache Spark version `2.3.0`. I use the following code:

```
PipelineModel.read().load(path);
```

I get the following logs:

```
2018-08-22 19:32:58.841  INFO 15540 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore     : Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 216.6 KB, free 1999.0 MB)
2018-08-22 19:32:58.904  INFO 15540 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore     : Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 20.5 KB, free 1999.0 MB)
2018-08-22 19:32:58.911  INFO 15540 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.spark.SparkContext            : Created broadcast 0 from textFile at ReadWrite.scala:382
```

I tried to use try-catch but there is no Exception thrown. Prior to the loading of the `PipelineModel` the `SparkSession` is initialized using the following code:

```
spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("Application Name")
            .master("local[*]")
            .getOrCreate();
```

I run the code directly from the IDE and Spark is used in the project as Maven dependencies. I have no problem writing the `PipelineModel` but unfortunately I cannot load it back. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you assigning the value to some variable? Is it returning null?